# Script in vb to copy files from one directory on server and paste it into a different directory

Tags: vb.net

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a script that will work.  All I want to do is have a "failover script" that will copy files from a directory on my server and paste it into a different folder on a different server on the network.

Comment: You want to pasted it by server, then do you have the right to access the server? If not, then even any script that tested to work and give it to you will still not work. Cause your program not have the right.

Comment: Yes I do have the correct rights to the server.  It should be a pretty easy script but I can't seem to find the right one to do just what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just use copy method
[Microsoft Copy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory.aspx)

[TUtorial copy from FTP to server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18739/Copy-from-FTP-server-to-local-Server-through-VB-Ne)